# Where is the realization of interface located in python module?

Tags: python, micropython, lego-mindstorms-ev3

Here is the code to which I can't find the realization in a .py file:

```
def distance(self):
    """Measures the relative distance between the sensor and an object using
    infrared light.

    Returns:
        :ref:`relativedistance`: Relative distance ranging from 0 (closest)
        to 100 (farthest).

    """
    pass
```

[contents of module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM9e1.png)

Comment: An image of a directory listing tells us absolutely nothing - what is the actual context in which you found this code?  It might be from an abstract class: each concrete subclass (describing a physical type of sensor) would override it with an actual implementation suitable for that particular sensor.  Or it might be a "stub" that just gives Python documentation for code that isn't implemented in Python (a C extension module, perhaps).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown is a class method that does nothing, so I assume you think there is a class definition somewhere else in the module that subclasses it and overrides that method? You'll just have to search for it.

If the class definition that contains the function you show is called `BaseClass` then you're looking for something like

```
class MyClass(BaseClass):
    
    # some other stuff here
    
    def distance(self):
        # this is what you are looking for
```

Obviously `MyClass` is an example name, it might be called anything.